# FFmpeg - What muxer do i need to save an AAC audio stream

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, aac

I'm developing Android application, and im using ffmpeg for conversion of files.
I want my binary file to be as slim as possible since i don't have many input formats and output formats, and my operation is quite basic.And of course not to bloat the APK.

In my program ffmpeg receives a file, and copys the audio stream (`-acodec copy`), the audio stream will always be aac (`mp4a`). What i need is to save the stream to file.
My command looks like this : `ffmpeg -i {Input} -vn -acodec copy output.aac`.

What muxer do i need to for muxing aac to file? I have tried `flv,mp3,mov` but i always get
`Unable to find a suitable output format for 'output.aac'`, so these options are wrong.
I don't need an encoder for stream copy [btw](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy).

Side note: this command work flawlessly on full installation of ffmpeg , but I don't know which muxer it uses. If there is a way to output the muxer it uses from regular ffmpeg run, it would work too.

Comment: That's pretty strange. .aac is just raw aac frames with adts header. Ffmpeg should be able to handle it. Try -f raw or -r adts.

Comment: You need the adts muxer: `-f adts`

Comment: That worked, please add an answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 6):

A common file format for AAC is BMFF/MOV/MP4/M4A.  If you specify the `m4a` file extension, FFmpeg will take care of it for you.

```
ffmpeg -i {input} -vn -acodec copy output.m4a
```

If you just want raw AAC, you can use ADTS as a lightweight container of sorts, as Mulvya suggested.

```
ffmpeg -i {input} -vn -acodec copy -f adts output.aac
```

Comment: Thank you. Was searching for a while on how to export raw AAC. '-f adts' was the trick

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the -f for me to work (on FFmpeg 3.22):
ffmpeg -i {input} -vn -acodec copy -f adts output.m4a

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `adts` to `--enable-muxer` when configuring ffmpeg, eg. `./configure --disable-everything (...) --enable-muxer=adts`. Then you will be able to save to `.aac` file